# Conditionally yield nothing in one line in python

Tags: python, generator, flat

I have generator like

```
def not_nones(some_iterable):
    for item in some_iterable:
        if item is not None:
            yield item
```

But since "flat is better than nested", I would like to do this in one line, like:

```
def not_nones(some_iterable):
    for item in some_iterable:
        yield item if item is not None else None
```

But this will actually make `None` an item of the generator.
Is it possible to yield nothing in a one-liner anyway?

Comment: I don't see much wrong with your code the way it is

Comment: But Python also says that explicit is better than implicit. Python is not the language for you if you want everything to be squashed down to the fewest lines possible. You can write very elegant Python code without driving for the fewest possible lines.

Comment: Your first example is the optimal way to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just return a generator expression:

```
def not_nones(iterable):
    return (item for item in iterable if item is not None)
```

Or for a *real* one-liner:

```
not_nones = lambda it: (i for i in it if i is not None)
```

which at this point is getting more into code-golf territory.

But really, there's not much wrong with your current code; it does what it needs to do, in a reasonable way. Your code is what I would have written in this situation.

Comment: The generator expression was what I did not think of.
But since you and other users here approved my initial code with nesting, I'll keep it that way for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.ifilter()`. Given the right predicate function it provides exactly the functionality you are implementing here.

Example:

```
import itertools

# make up data
l = [1, None, 2, None, 3]
# predicate function
not_none = lambda x: x is not None
# filter out None values
not_nones = itertools.ifilter(not_none, l)

print list(not_nones) # prints [1, 2, 3]
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter